# bash function to perform a sanity check on nginx files

Tags: bash, nginx

I am trying to write a function which performs a sanity check of files before I move them into `/etc/nginx/site-available`.
There are located in my home directory and are modified regularly.

The only modification done in those files is to add a `server_name`.

They look like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.com;
    server_name  www.domain.com;


    server_name  mynsite1.com;
    server_name  www.mysite1.com;

    server_name  mysite2.com;
    server_name  www.mysite2.com;

    server_name  mysite3.com;
    server_name  www.mysite3.com;

    server_name  mysite4.com;
    server_name  www.mysite4.com;


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com-access.log  main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/domain.com-error.log warn;

    root   /var/www/docroot; 
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

Here is the function I have right now:

```
verify_nginx()
{
  if [ ! -s "$file1" ]; then
    echo  "-> File \"$file1\" is empty or do not exist" | ts
    exit 1
  elif [ ! -s "$file2" ]; then
    echo  "-> File \"$file2\" is empty or do not exist" | ts
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

I would also like to add `nginx -t -c /homedir/file1` in the function but I get the following error:

> ```
> nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /homedir/file:1
> nginx: configuration file /homedir/file test failed
> ```

Indeed `nginx -c` is expecting `nginx.conf` which does not include my files in my homedir.

I could put my files in `/etc/nginx/site-available` which is included in `nginx.conf` but I want to perform the sanity check before I move the files to the correct location.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to test the configuration file located somewhere else than in `/etc/nginx/site-available` using `nginx`?
2. What kind of sanity checks should be performed on `nginx` files?

Comment: Write your own minimal `nginx.conf` that points at your custom directory and test that with `-t -c`?

Comment: Pull out the bits of the file that change and compose the final file from the "master" input file and independently verifiable input snippets so you know that the are good before you compose the final file?

Comment: @Etan Reisner. Nice idea for the minimal nginx.conf.  How would you pull out the bits of a file?

Comment: Manually. You said you only need to add new `server_name` lines, right? So take your config file above, remove all the `server_name` lines and that's your "minimal config". Then just put all the server names in a file (or many files) and write a small shell/awk script that sticks them in the correct place in that config file.

Answer (score 0):

The files you're trying to sanity-check are not nginx config files, therefore (understandably) `nginx -t` says they're invalid. The `-c` flag expects "[an alternative configuration file](http://linux.die.net/man/8/nginx)", not a single `server` block. `server` blocks live inside an `http` block.

If you want to run `nginx -t` you need to pass it a proper config file, which would *include* the files you're attempting to modify. You could, as Etan Reisner suggests, simply write a dummy `nginx.conf` that includes your files, something like this might work (I'm not on a machine with nginx installed atm, so you may have to add a few more stub directives):

```
http {
  include path/to/files/*;
}
```

Then you can run `nginx -t -c dummy_nginx.conf`.

This has a problem though; you could still have any number of errors that are only revealed when your real config file is loaded.

Instead, you can verify your real config file with your changes before they're loaded by simply calling `nginx -t` before you [`reload`](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/nginx/how-to-configure-nginx#start-stop-reload); you could wrap this in a bash function if you wanted:

```
safe_reload() {
  nginx -t &&
    service nginx reload # only runs if nginx -t succeeds
}
```

You should also have some sort of backup or restore mechanism. This could be as simple as copying your old config files to parallel `*.bak` files, but much more pleasant is using a VCS like Mercurial or Git. You check in each iteration of your configs that succeed, and then you can easily revert to the previous known good configuration if anything goes wrong.